# Why am I getting undefined method `comments' in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have API with The Movie Database (TMDb). I want the app to review individually. I have created all the things but this error makes be sucked? How can I get rid of this?

My error is:

> ```
> NoMethodError in ReviewsController#create
>
> undefined method `comments' for #<Review:0x00000005278fa8> Did you mean? comment comment? comment=
> ```

```
 @review = current_user.reviews.new(review_params.merge(movie_id: @movie.id))

 if @review.save  # I got error here!!!
   flash[:success] = "Review saved!"
   redirect_to root_path
 else
   flash[:alert] = "Woops! It seems there was an error."
   redirect_to root_path
 end
```

Review Params

```
def review_params
  params.require(:review).permit(:comment)
end
```

My `movie.rb` is:

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
    validates :title, :release_date, :released, :runtime, :popularity, :language, :budget, :average_vote, :vote_count, :tmdb_id, presence: true
    has_many :reviews
end
```

My `review.rb` is:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie

  validates :user, :movie, :comments, presence: true
end
```

My `user.rb` is:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  validates :username, presence: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :username
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  has_many :reviews
end
```

Comment: Please add the `reviews` schema.

Comment: In `review.rb`, you're requiring the review to have comments, where do the comments come from?

Comment: Also, what does `review_params` look like?

Comment: What does `Review.columns_hash[:comments]` return?

Comment: *My review.rb is:* -- Yes, but what is your `db/migrate/....create_reviews.rb`?  Alternatively what does `$ rails c` then `Review.find 1` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error looks like it is coming for the validation you have on the `Review` model.  The line

```
validates :user, :movie, :comments, presence: true
```

is effectively going to call `@review.comments.present?` before attempting to actually save the record to the DB.  However, the error is telling you that there is a problem with `@review.comments` - the method `#comments` doesn't exist on the `@review` object.

The error you have shown is also trying to give you a hint where it reads "Did you mean comment, comment?, comment=", indicating that there is a method with a similar name (the singular `comment`) and maybe you have a typo.  You may just need to adjust the validation in `app/models/review.rb` to

```
validates :user, :movie, :comment, presence: true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solved my problem. I think I am a fool.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message says:

> undefined method 'comments' for `#<Review:0x00000005278fa8>`. Did you mean? comment comment? comment=

This syntax `#<Review:0x00000005278fa8>` refers to an instance of the Review class.

Check out this code:

```
class Review
  def show
    puts "I'm a review"
  end
end

review = Review.new
puts review

review.show
review.comments

--output:--
#<Review:0x007fa4db0a5bb8>
I'm a review

1.rb:10:in `<main>': undefined method `comments' for #<Review:0x007fa4db0a5bb8> (NoMethodError)
```

Does that error look familiar?  The error says that there is no method named comments() defined in the Review class.

Your error even asks you

> Did you mean? comment comment? comment=

i.e. Is your method name actually spelled 'comment', 'comment?', or 'comment='?

The reason the error occurs here:

```
if @review.save  # I got error here!!!
```

is because that line of code causes the validations that you specified in your Review class to execute:

> Creating and saving a new record will send an SQL INSERT operation to
>   the database. Updating an existing record will send an SQL UPDATE
>   operation instead. Validations are typically run before these commands
>   are sent to the database. If any validations fail, the object will be
>   marked as invalid and Active Record will not perform the INSERT or
>   UPDATE operation. This avoids storing an invalid object in the
>   database. You can choose to have specific validations run when an
>   object is created, saved, or updated.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Here's an example from the rails guide:

> ```
> class Person < ApplicationRecord
>   validates :name, presence: true
> end
>
> Person.create(name: "John Doe").valid? # => true
> Person.create(name: nil).valid? # => false
> ```
>
> As you can see, our validation lets us know that our Person is not
>   valid without a name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error message the field is called `comment` not `comments`